# "Down-resolution" a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of shape `[5sx,5sy,5sz]` and I’d like to create a tensor with shape `[sx,sy,sz]` where the value of each element is:

```
new_array[x,y,z] = mean(array[5x:5x+5,5y:5y+5,5z:5z+5])
```

I could do this in a loop, but is there a faster one-line approach?

(I'd really ideally like to do it where the size of the origin array is *not* an integer multiple of the new one, but that seems like a much harder question, and I thought this would be a good first step at least.)

Comment: In pytorch I think the following broadly does it:
kernel_size=[5,5,5]
torch.nn.Conv3d(in_channels=1,out_channels=1,kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=kernel_size, padding=0)(tensor)

Comment: The new array must be smaller of at least 5 elements or you have to add a padding after the last elements. Think about the last element in x, if you do the mean from that element to the one 5 elements after, you point your index outside the matrix

Comment: Why the approach you wrote on the comments shouldn't be good for your purposes?

Comment: Well, it probably is to be honest DaSim

Answer (score 1):

You could use scikit-image block_reduce:

```
import numpy as np
import skimage.measure

arr5 = np.random.rand(20, 20, 20)
arr  = skimage.measure.block_reduce(arr5, (5, 5, 5), np.mean)
print(f'arr.shape = {arr.shape}')
print(f'arr5[:5, :5, :5].mean() = {arr5[:5, :5, :5].mean()}')
print(f'arr[0, 0, 0] = {arr[0, 0, 0]}')
```

output:

```
arr.shape = (4, 4, 4)
arr5[:5, :5, :5].mean() = 0.47200241666948467
arr[0, 0, 0] = 0.4720024166694848
```

If you're dealing with large arrays and you have a GPU available I would advise you to look into pytorch's average pooling.

Comment: Average pooling may be exactly what I'm looking for in the case the arrays aren't perfectly aligned - thanks, looking into it further.

Comment: what do you mean by "in the case the arrays aren't perfectly aligned"?